# ULN2003A to sink current when collector volatge less than base voltage

Tags: ttl, darlington

I am trying to drive a opto-isolator using ULN2003A. My question is that the ULN2003A datasheet [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf) only states the maximum voltage that can be sinked, which is 50v.

In my application, the voltage to be sinked is less than 5 volt as I am driving opto-coupler which is pulled high at 3.3v with current limiting resistor. The opto-isolator is then connected to output pin of ULN2003A which needs to be grounded to complete the circuit.

Thus what is the minimum collector voltage with respect to base which can be sinked?

p.s. The datasheet mentions that the "com" can be left unconnected when driving resistance based loads.

[image: ULN2003A]
[image: ULN2003A_Internal]

Comment: You don't sink voltage, you sink current.

Comment: I understand but I wanted to make the question a bit more clear as the current is around 16 mA and the voltage drops at 0.9v when the opto isolator circuit is complete.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't make it more clear, you made it into nonsense. The part isn't spec'ed to "sink" any particular voltage. It is spec'ed to saturate at no more than 1.1 V, and I guess it's spec'ed to withstand 50 V with low leakage when off.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I have edited the question and corrected it.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to use a ULN2003 to drive an opto-isolator? Opto's are usually pretty low-current devices so I'd expect you could drive it directly from whatever you're using as a controller (and bypass the ULN completely). If your controller really can't sink enough current to properly activate the opto, then use a single transistor (and not a darlington configuration like the ULN).

Comment: @brhans i have shiftregister 74hc595 which is responsible for activating 8 opto couplers. 74hc595 cannot sink alll this current thats why uln2003 sits in between. Its also easy to control all 8 opto coupler by single ic than adding 8 transistors.

Answer (score 2):

> the ULN2003A datasheet here only states the maximum voltage that can be sinked, which is 50v.

First, we don't talk about "sinking" voltage. We sink current. The spec you're referring to says that when the ULN2003A is in cut-off mode, it can *withstand* 50 V applied to the collector and not leak more than 100 uA.

> Thus what is the minimum collector voltage with respect to base which can be sinked?

Again, you can't "sink" voltage. The spec you are looking for is the V<sub>CE</sub> saturation voltage. It's included in the specs you posted, and the maximum is 1.1 V.

> I always thought that the base voltage should be greater than the collector voltage

In saturation, we usually estimate that a typical NPN BJT can pull its collector node down to about 0.2 V. Since this is a darlington configuration, the overall collector-emitter voltage drop for the ULN2003A includes the base-emitter voltage of the "lower" transistor, plus the \$V_{CE}\$ voltage of the "upper" transistor. Using the typical values this is 0.7 + 0.2 or 0.9 V, which is exactly the number given in the datasheet for the typical behavior at low currents.

Comment: Thanks. So it means that UNL2003A will not work in this case! Should I drop the base voltage in this case?

Comment: I didnt' say it won't work. It depends on the forward voltage of your optocoupler's LED. ULN2003A is probably overkill though, and you could just use a jelly-bean transistor and a couple of resistors (although, looking at pricing on ULN2003A, it probably makes nearly no difference).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry as I misunderstood. I have tested my circuit and its working fine. I chose ULN2003A because I need to trigger 8 optocoupler's and it presents a neat way of doing that with simplified circuit(and also it is very very cheap here).

Answer (score 1):

Because the 2003 has Darlington outputs, and your optocoupler current is presumably in the range of ~10 mA, you should count on an output voltage of about a volt, maybe a bit less. Note from the data sheet that at 100 mA the output voltage is a max of 1.1 volts. Your presumed opto current is so much less than the data sheet deals with that I can't be certain of just how it will behave. So figure a volt.

Comment: what do you mean by " So figure a volt "?. Will the ULN2003A able to sink the current (16mA @ .9 volts)?

Comment: He means you can guess that the output voltage will be about a volt. But there isn't enough information in the datasheet to be sure. The question isn't whether the ULN2003A can sink the current, it's will it pull its output low enough to turn on an LED and give you enough headroom to reasonably choose a current limiting resistor.

Comment: OK but I always thought that the base voltage should be greater than the collector voltage. In this case, the base voltage is 5 volts (from a shift register) and the collector voltage is 0.9 volts only. How would the transistor allow connection between collector and emitter in this case?

Comment: 1. The presence of Rb on the input means the transistor base is not the same as the applied voltage on the chip's pin. 2. Even with a single (not darlington) transistor, the collector can be driven to lower voltage than the base in saturation.

Comment: As a matter of fact, saturation is defined as having the collector-emitter voltage less than the base-emitter voltage. Collector voltage greater than base voltage is a mark of linear operation, is a useful gauge of when the transistor is no longer able to linearly amplify a signal.